# Why do homes lose 50% of their value every decade in Turkey?

Tags: real-estate, international, turkey

Homes lose **about** 50% of their value every decade in this country. Why is that?

Source:

1. 2014 - present https://www.zingat.com/ankara-bolge-raporu
2. 2005 - 2015 https://www.zingat.com/blog/istanbulda-10-yilda-ev-fiyatlari-ne-kadar-artti/
3. Factor in the devaluation of TRY by comparing it to any stable currency https://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-try-historical-data for relevant data points listed above
4. Another source 2010 - present https://tradingeconomics.com/turkey/housing-index

Comment: It would probably help to explain what information you're pulling from the various sites.  Two of them appear to be Turkish so most people here aren't going to be able to read it/trust Google's translation enough to understand the calculations you're making and to formulate a response.

Comment: I did explain in #3

Comment: It's also worth noting that there are countries like Japan where it is well-known that homes depreciate and become basically worthless after 30 years.  https://www.rethinktokyo.com/2018/06/06/depreciate-limited-life-span-japanese-home/1527843245

Comment: I'm referring to the average house price in meter square (this includes the value of the attached land), adjusted for the local currency devaluation (check #3 again if this part isn't clear).

Comment: Do home sales in Turkey also include land? In many countries land is not included in the home ownership, only the building. In which case - why would it appreciate?

Comment: Do home sales in Turkey also include land? Yes

Comment: Your first two links are in Turkish.  I don't speak Turkish.  Google Translate and the graph on the page shows a pretty sharp appreciation.  I assume you are taking different numbers from the pages you've quoted to come up with your 50% calculation.  But you're not explaining how you got from point A to point B to point C.

Comment: Factor in the devaluation of TRY by comparing it to any stable currency such as USD https://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-try-historical-data for relevant data points listed above e.g 2005 - 2015. Avg price in 2005 is 2x. Avg price in 2015 is x in USD/EUR/any stable currency, roughly.

Comment: I understand what you're saying.  My point is, if you formulate a question by saying "I got data point X from page 1 and data point Y from page 2 and calculate depreciation as 50% by dividing X/Y", that's much more likely to be clear to other users rather than hoping that they'll go to the same page you went to, find the same values, and perform the same calculation.  Particularly when linking to foreign language sites.

Comment: If you are factoring in the value in USD, and considering that your local currency is devaluing - that is not a matter of home prices devaluing, that is a matter of local economy relative to the US. Very different matter.

Answer (score 2):

Many reasons could cause homes to lose value instead of appreciate. I won't opine about Turkish real estate per se, since I know next to nothing about their economic, cultural, and institutional structures. Nevertheless, here are just a few reasons in general real estate could depreciate in a given area:

- The population is shrinking, thereby reducing demand
- Cultural reasons, i.e. people think it is "gross" to live in someone else's old home.
- Local/Traditional Building materials for the area are not durable and depreciate quicker.
- There is no change in land title, thus real estate is less valuable and more susceptible to depreciation.
- The local economy habitually overbuilds increasing supply beyond sustainable demand.
- Government subsidies to move people into newer, safer, construction.
- Bad economic conditions such as low liquidity in the economy.

This list isn't exhaustive, but it should give you an idea on what could be causing the phenomenon.

Comment: Thank you. How can I find historical data for these? Any pointers, metrics, etc? 1. "Bad economic conditions such as low liquidity in the economy" 2. "The local economy habitually overbuilds increasing supply beyond sustainable demand" 3. "There is no change in land title, thus real estate is less valuable and more susceptible to depreciation."

I would like to understand how this works so I can "predict" the future better

Comment: @user117384 this site is for answerable questions, not discussions and threads. You'll need to educate yourself on how real estate works in Turkey, it's not something that can be done in one answer to one question.

Comment: So, no way to measure liquidity in an economy?

Comment: Look for economic data, housing starts, measures of money in circulation like M2, etc. Start building models from there.